# AD7545JN problems

Tags: arduino, dac

I have a couple of [AD7545JN](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/66281/INTERSIL/AD7545JN.html) DACs that I want to drive some proportional vales with, using an Arduino Mega.

My main problems is that I'm only getting about 8V at OUT1 of it with Vref at 10V. And I'm getting some strange noise I can't quite explain.

This is a capture with the Mega ramping up from 0 - 4095, yellow line is output and green is Vref
[image]

[image]

DB0-DB11 is connected to Pin22-33 on the Mega

WR&CS is tied together to Pin 2

A&DGND is tied to GND

RFB is floating

Vref is at 10V

I have tried putting Vdd to 5V from the mega and together with Vref.

There is obviously something I'm not understanding, so any advice is appreciated

Comment: Did you mean DAC instead of ADC?

Comment: Yeah, he did. I've edited the post. @Littleme, can we see a schematic please? Just saying it's an Arduino means nothing to those of us who have only used AVRs on custom boards.

Comment: Is this DAC on breadboard? That looks like 6V to me, not 8V. What is the supply voltage of the DAC? How long between writes to the DAC?

Comment: The DAC is mounted on a prototyping board, the wires are about 5cm long.
The the oscilloscope only shows 6V in the pictures there yes, it was very finicky.
I don't have a schematic right now, but could make one later
The pins 22-33 and 2 are just general purpose 5V I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a current output multiplying DAC - you don't operate it it into an open circuit. It's meant to feed a transimpedance amplifier like this: -

[image]

Comment: Hmm that might be it, I was thinking I could at-least get something usable out it without an opamp, as the datasheet mention it inverting the voltage. What would be the best way to get around that?
I have a some LM324 I can try it with tomorrow

Comment: @Littleme it's all down to how much accuracy you want. The LM324 has an input offset error of 2 mV typically and a 40 nA bias input bias current that adds to the errors. Read the DAC data sheet - there is an option to swap OUT with REF and get a voltage out but it cannot be loaded without incurring more errors and this means you probably still need to use an op-amp that is JFET input or CMOS

Comment: The voltage is controlled by a joystick so I image the accuracy isn't that important, a 8bit DAC would honestly be more than good enought.
I flipped the wires around and I have a very smooth and linear line now. Thanks for that tip. I'll report back tomorrow when I have played around with this some more

Comment: I can only reiterate what my answer and previous comment said.